# Cmake generated VS project looks untidy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I have converted an open source project ([Sundials](https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials)) with cmake to a Visual Studio project. Compilation seems to work, which I am very glad about.

However the generated project looks a little messy in solution explorer of VS. All the header files of the project are sorted into the external dependencies folder and there is no header files folder. I can't really see what belongs to the project and what is external to it.

Is this intended behavior of cmake, or can I do something about it? May I safely move files from external folder to a header folder manually?

Comment: Try to use the 'Show All Files' option in Solution Explorer?

Comment: @stijn: hmm, just tried it, but that did not change anything about the wrong placement of the header files

Comment: For VS projects it is common to add include files and sources files to your `add_executable` or `add_library` call. To structure the solution in the IDE you could use the `source_group` command of `CMake`.

Comment: @vre:I am afraid I am one of those stupids who usually never look at makefiles. I just ran the cmake GUI to convert the project. Is there an option in the GUI that does what you mean?

Comment: Adding the headers to the projects needs a change in the CMake script code itself and can't be added by an options/variable changes in CMake's GUI.

Comment: @vre That comment should be an answer. Not adding the header files is a common mistake, because you won't notice the difference unless you are working with an IDE yourself. I would argue that this is worth writing a bug report to the library maintainer, as it's a low-impact change on the scripts and the project will really be borderline-unusable in IDEs without this.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: okay, now I understand. Then manually changing the cmakefile has no advantage over manually rearranging the project structure because it would be something to be repeated on every new release. I will inform the library maintainer about the issue.